# UBUNTU 16.04.6 not showing Dashboard, sidebars and menu bars

Tags: 16.04, command-line, unity

I am a regular user of Ubuntu 16.04.6. Recently, I was trying to install python3.6 and set this as default. But due some other package I had to remove this version. I uninstalled python3.6 and set `alias python=python2`. This is where it started to display bizarre things like not showing dashboard, sidebar, et. I don't know what blunder I made while uninstalling but it's getting tougher for me work without dashboard and terminal (not able to open terminal also). I tried most of the online solutions and nothing favoured me yet.

I have attached the image of the terminal below for more information.

Any help would be appreciated!

[Output of the terminal. Entered tty1 by 'CTRL+ALT+F1'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xN50j.jpg)

Comment: Did it have python 3.5 originally? If so why not reinstall that? You should keep notes on what you are overwriting or removing in case things go wrong.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion. No it didn't. I had to install for running some applications. Now I removed python3.5 from the system and left with default i.e. python2.7. The scenario still remains the same. I am still not able to access terminal or dashboard. It's high time that I stuck in here. Pull me out of this error...

Answer (score 0):

It seems the issue is with Python 3.5 package. Try running the command:

```
ln -s /usr/lib/python3.5/plat-*/_sysconfigdata_m.py /usr/lib/python3.5/
```

Then reboot

Hope it helps.

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Arijit for timely reply. Now I completely removed python3.5 packages from the system. So above mentioned command won't work. At present, I have python2.7 as default. Still it is not working though. Any other ways to rid of this error.

Comment: I uninstalled python3.5 and set python2.7 as default. Even after making these changes, still not displaying the dashboard.